# Trying to convert date string to epoch format. Timezone is not being factored in on a particular environment

Tags: python, date

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                          

import subprocess                                              
import time                                                    
import os                                                      

date = 'Thu Dec 12 21:30:48 EST 2019'                          

date_split = date.split()                                      
timezone = date_split[4]                                       
os.environ['TZ'] = timezone                                       
date_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S {} %Y'.format(timezone)       
date_epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date, date_format)))

print(date_epoch)
```

On my local workstation (python 2.7.5), this works fine. I've ensured that timezone is being factored in by modifying the value of `os.environ['TZ']` and checking that the output changes.

However, on a different system (python 2.7.12), there's a mismatch between this script's output and the actual date (in epoch format). I suspected that timezone wasn't being factored in and I was right. On this system, when modifying the value of `os.environ['TZ']`, I don't see a corresponding change in the output.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: I don't know why you expect changing `os.environ['TZ']` to make a difference. It's only changing Python objects, not the OS settings.

Comment: @MarkRansom But changing `os.environ['TZ']` was indeed making a difference. Changing this variable produced a large delta in the `date_epoch` variable. The only issue is that this change would only occur in one of my environments and not the other for some reason.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you, it's just that I wouldn't have predicted it to make any difference.  I expect `mktime` and `strptime` to call the underlying C functions which wouldn't look at the Python objects at all.  Which means I don't know what's going on, so I didn't leave an answer.